# How to avoid round off errors when adding fractions in JAVA

Tags: java

I need to add up a series of fractions, e.g. 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ..., and return a double. How can I avoid or minimize the round off error?

Comment: Till where? Constraints?

Comment: For any length passed as an argument in the method.

Comment: you want the output `0.5` for the division of 1 by 2 e.g. `1/2` ? and then sum all?

Comment: Exactly. And the sum will be returned as a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative if you really want to preserve accuracy, and don't want to rely on the precision settings of BigDecimal, is to use the Apache Fractions library:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html

e.g.:

```
Fraction f1 = Fraction.getFraction(1, 2);
f1 = f1.add(Fraction.getFraction(1, 3));
f1 = f1.add(Fraction.getFraction(1, 4));

System.out.println(f1);
System.out.println(f1.doubleValue());
```

... prints:

13/12

1.0833333333333333

Note - this class uses integers internally to represent the numerator and denominator. If you want to use really big numbers in your fractions then the math3 version of the library provides a BigFraction class instead backed by BigInteger.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you use `BigDecimal` for the calculations. It's the best alternative when you have to do float and double calculations with maximum precision.

Comment: You still have to specify a precision and can't represent irrational fractions perfectly.

Comment: True that, but is an alternative that doesn't require an external library. OP needs to specify the exact type of fractions and if external libraries are OK.